# PHP select data text range from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, html-table, range

I want to select a range from an items table that have a list of item numbers as follows :

```
id  item_no  qty date
1   1l500bk  15  2015-03-20
2   1l501bu  10  2015-03-20
3   1l1501ye  5  2015-03-21
4   1l1520bu  5  2015-03-21
5   1l1521bk  1  2015-03-22
```

And I've created a form with two input fields that asks the user to enter From item number & TO item number, as follows :

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="From Item Number" name="item1">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="To Item Number" name="item2">
```

Now, When I type FROM **1l1500** - TO **1l1600** .. It should output all values within this range, but its not ! the output shows nothing . However, if I type **1l1500bk** to **1l1521bk** it will only show 1 output ( **1l1500bk** ) ?!

Here is the PHP code after page submission :

```
$query = "SELECT *,SUM(qty) from s_{$value} WHERE item_no BETWEEN '".$_POST['item1']."' AND '".$_POST['item2']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr><td align=center width=19%>{$value}</td><td align=center width=19%>{$row['item_no']}</td><td align=center>{$row['qty']}</td><td align=center>{$row['date']}</td></tr>";

}
```

I hope this makes sense for you guys, I can't seem to find what is the problem !
Thank you

---

Thanks for @Waleed Ahmed for his help
The solution for my question is just by grouping up the id as follows :

```
$query = "SELECT *,SUM(qty) from s_{$value} WHERE item_no BETWEEN '".$_POST['item1']."' AND  '".$_POST['item2']."'" GROUP BY id;
```

Plus : If you want to do partial text search

```
$length = max(strlen($_POST['item1']), strlen($_POST['item2'])); 

$query = "SELECT *,SUM(qty) from s_{$value} WHERE SUBSTRING(item_no, 1, ".$length.") BETWEEN '".$_POST['item1']."' AND  '".$_POST['item2']."'" GROUP BY id;
```

This output data even if you don't type the whole item number.

Comment: [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) does not work on alphanumeric values like that. You end up with a [`Type Conversion`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks but how can I fix this ?

Comment: I wish you would help me out rather being a police over here. How on earth this question is duplicate.

Comment: How is providing you a link to a similar question `being a police over here` and not help? It is a similar type of question. Did you try the answer there to see if it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this query , it will show only one result as an output. To use aggregate function that is (sum(qty)) here, you have to use "Group By" word to show all results. For example

Not tested, Hope it will work

```
$query = "SELECT *,SUM(qty) from s_{$value} WHERE item_no BETWEEN '".$_POST['item1']."' AND '".$_POST['item2']."'" GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Wow, it works as needed !!! Thanks man, can't believe how this small fix changes the whole output. +1